# Tenacious/Unsung Hero badge description confusion

Tags: discussion, explanation

> Tenacious = "Zero score accepted answers: more than 5 and 20% of total"
>
> Unsung Hero = " Zero score accepted answers: more than 10 and 25% of total"

I get what most of that mean, you have 5/10 zero score accepted answers.  What I don't get is the 20%/25% of total.  20% of what total?

I may be just being very thick but that is confusing.

Comment: My guess is it means '20%/25% of all your accepted answers'.

Comment: Hmmm ... that means you can only get this badge if you've accepted scores on 25 or 40 questions.

Comment: Yeah.. that's what it looks like. It's a _gold_ badge, after all (the unsung one) :-)

Comment: @m.Alin I'm not sure what you are getting at.  There are many people who have far more than 25 or 40 accepted answers so this badge is automatically excluded from them, in fact the only way to get this badge, if that were true, would be to just be starting out.

Comment: That badge line feels more like a "consolation prize" than something that you (@placeholder) could get.

Comment: @W5VO We don't need no steenking badges!

Answer (score 7):

The *sentiment* of that line of badges is that a considerable percentage of your answers are accepted but not upvoted. I feel like the descriptions are being a bit stingy with words. Basically, each badge has two conditions, a minimum number of answers that qualify, and a minimum ratio of answers that qualify to answers that don't qualify. Let me try to fully describe each condition that must be met for the *Unsung Hero* badge:

- You must have more than 10 accepted answers with a score of zero.
- Your percentage of zero score accepted answers out of your total number of accepted answers must be greater than 25%.

\$\dfrac{\text{Number of Zero Score Accepted Answers}}{\text{Total Number of Accepted Answers}}\gt25\%\$

To earn this badge, you must have at least 10 zero score accepted answers, which could happen if you're just starting out. If an established user with 100 accepted answers with scores wanted to earn this badge, they would need to get 34 new answers with a score of zero.

Another way of rewording it to be more explicit:

> **Zero score accepted answers: more than 10** *(zero score accepted answers)* **and** *(the number of zero score accepted answers is more than)* **25% of** *(the)* **total** *(number of accepted answers)*.

Comment: Confusion gone!  May I suggest your version be put into the change queue?